# How do I convert has_one_attached to has_many_attached to an exising table with has_one attachments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations, rails-activestorage

I have a `Message` model which had

```
  class Message < ApplicationRecord
    has_one_attached :attachment
```

but now I need to convert it to :

```
  class Message < ApplicationRecord
    has_many_attached :attachments
```

to enable multiple attachments for messages
So I changed `has_one_attached` to `has_many_attached` in the model `Message`

but when I run `message.attachments.attached?` it returns `false` to existing attachment. It works correctly for the newly attached files.

Should I be adding a migration or a one time `rake` task which manually adds/converts the attachments?

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 10):

The reason why `message.attachments.attached?` returns false is because you changed the name of the attribute from `attachment` to `attachments`. ActiveStorage saves that attribute name in the DB so if that name changes in the code, it can not find the old attachments anymore.

So either you don't change the attribute name (simplest solution) or you create a [data migration](https://github.com/ilyakatz/data-migrate) like this

```
    ActiveStorage::Attachment.where(name: "attachment")
                             .where(record_type: "Message")
                             .update(name: "attachments")
```